# Error function is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a translation for a web page, but keep getting an error "changeLocale()" isn't defined

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    function changeLocale(){
        if (document.getElementsByClassName('locFin').style.display == 'block') {
            document.getElementsByClassName('locFin').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementsByClassName('locEn').style.display = 'block';
        } else{
            document.getElementsByClassName('locEn').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementsByClassName('locFin').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

that's how i've defined the function, and here's where i call it.

```
<button onclick="changeLocale();">Change</button>
```

Comment: It's a scope issue. The function `changeLocale()` is defined inside another function, and it's not available in the global scope.

Comment: Event attributes, like `onclick`, can only reach names in the global scope and `changeLocale()` isn't a global. It only exists inside of the `window.onload` handler `function` it's defined within.

Comment: If you are just defining a function, you can do it even before DOM rendering is completed, so you do not need to wrap it into `window.onload`.

Answer (score 1):

changeLocale() hasn't been defined in the global scope, it's only defined in the window.onload scope.  Try defining the function outside of the window.onload handler.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeLocale(){
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('locFin').style.display == 'block') {
        document.getElementsByClassName('locFin').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementsByClassName('locEn').style.display = 'block';
    } else{
        document.getElementsByClassName('locEn').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementsByClassName('locFin').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>
```

or if you have to define it after loading, try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var changeLocale;
window.onload=function(){
  changeLocale = function(){
      if (document.getElementsByClassName('locFin').style.display == 'block') {
          document.getElementsByClassName('locFin').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementsByClassName('locEn').style.display = 'block';
      } else{
          document.getElementsByClassName('locEn').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementsByClassName('locFin').style.display = 'block';
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

After defining it as above, your button should work.

```
<button onclick="changeLocale();">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function can stand on it's own, it shouldn't be inside `window.onLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the function changeLocale outside of the `window.onload=function`. This is because of  problems with the scope.

When you define changeLocale inside the window.onload function, changeLocale is defined only within the scope of the window.onload function. `onclick`, in the html, can only access the scope of the global window object. Since it does not see a function named changeLocale in the window scope, it thinks it is not defined. To solve this, you must take the changeLocale function outside of the window.onload scope and declare it on the "global" window scope.